# Combine multiple list items and append it to a single row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I am reading a csv file with artist ID's and I need to get Artist genre data from Spotify API. But the problem is Spotify has multiple genres for a single artist(in JSON format) and I want to save all these in the same row (in pandas) using a comma separator.

eg. Hip-Hop, pop rap, dirty south rap.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
TOKEN = "BQCuNvMU0Gr_"
url1 = r"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"
headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(TOKEN)}

df = pd.read_csv('top_artists.csv',names=["Artist_URI","Artist_Name"])

#iterate over each artist 
for row_ID in df['ARTIST_ID'].iteritems():
 url = url1+row_ID
 r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) #each artist has a different URL
 json_data = r.json() 

 #get artist genre(s) and append to genre column
 for genre_data in json_data['genres']:

    df['genre'] = genre_1 + genre_2 + genre_3 ...
```

[Here is how the data looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnZSD.jpg)

Comment: You can just do a `.join()` on `json_data['genres']`

Comment: Can you provide the `json_data`?

Comment: {'external_urls': {'spotify': 
    'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1G9G7WwrXka3Z1r7aIDjI7'},
     'followers': {'href': None, 'total': 1053458},
     'genres': ['atl hip hop',
  'dirty south rap',
  'hip hop',
  'pop rap',
  'rap',
  'southern hip hop'],'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1G9G7WwrXka3Z1r7aIDjI7'

Answer (score 0):

```
TOKEN = "BQCuNvMU0Gr_"
url1 = r"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"
headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(TOKEN)}

df = pd.read_csv('top_artists.csv',names=["Artist_URI","Artist_Name"])

#iterate over each artist 
for row_ID in df['ARTIST_ID'].iteritems():
 url = url1+row_ID
 r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) #each artist has a different URL
 json_data = r.json() 

 #get artist genre(s) and append to genre column
 #No need of For Loop here
 genres_list = json_data['genres']
 df['genre'] = "".join(a)
```